# form submission within thickbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I have a contact form open in thickbox i want when user click on submit form data submit to my php that will process that data and show sucessfull msg back to thickbox.
php page is called but how i will get form data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First use thickbox's iframe feature to load the form in the thickbox.  Make sure you have jquery and thickbox loaded by putting this in the HTML head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/thickbox.js"></script>
<link href="/stylesheets/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then put a link on the page the loads the contact us form in the iframe:

```
<a href="/contact_us_form.php?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600&modal=true" class="thickbox" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
```

Your form should have markup that has this basic structure:

```
<div id="content">
  <form id="contact_us" action="/contact_us.php" method="POST">
     ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Now use jQuery to your form via AJAX.  Put this in the head of the HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
    $('#contact_us').submit(function(){ 
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(html) { 
        $('#content').html(html)
      })
      return false
    })
  })
</script>
```

What this does is:

1. Adds a function to the form to be called when the form is submitted.  It returns false to prevent the default behavior of a form submitting from happen.
2. This submit function will do an AJAX post, using the action of the form, which you set to `contact_us.php`.
3. Finally, this will take whatever content `contact_us.php` returns and replace the content of the div with the id content with that.

So make your `contact_us.php` script actually send the email or create a database record, whatever it does, and then have it return this HTML:

```
<p>Thank you for your submission!</p>

<p><a href="#" onclick="window.parent.tb_remove(); return false">Continue</a>
```

Obviously this can be anything you want, whatever message you want the end user to see.  The link shows you how to make the thickbox window go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot pjb3, its working infact you sent me the complete solution. i got the above line of js function but what is the purpose of below lines 
function(html) { 
        $('#content').html(html)
      })

Comment: It takes the body of the response of content_us.php, which is a snippet of HTML, and replaces the contents of the div in the thickbox window with that

Answer (score 2):

To post form data, one would need to use jQuery's serialize function.

Modifying the example above:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(html) { 
    $('#content').html(html);
});
```